# io.vertx.mysqlclient.MySQLPool.query ("").execute is never really executed and return nothing

Tags: mysql, kotlin, closures, vert.x, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying a very simple tentative to insert and select to/from MySql using vertx for the first time. It is funny to me that I can build and debug the application but I never get either ar.succeeded or failed.

How to execute the insert and select bellow? Do I have to enclose somehow client.query and subscribe it? I am complete stuck. All examples on internet I see follow this approach.

```
package com.mybank

import io.vertx.kotlin.mysqlclient.mySQLConnectOptionsOf
import io.vertx.kotlin.sqlclient.poolOptionsOf
import io.vertx.mysqlclient.MySQLClient
import io.vertx.mysqlclient.MySQLPool

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    var connectOptions = mySQLConnectOptionsOf(database = "mydb",
            host = "127.0.0.1",
            password = "q", port = 6603,
            user = "root")

    var poolOptions = poolOptionsOf(maxSize = 5)

    var client = MySQLPool.pool(connectOptions, poolOptions)

    client.query("INSERT INTO mytable('id','name') VALUES ('2','Jimis2')").execute { ar ->
        if (ar.succeeded()) {
            var rows = ar.result()
            var lastInsertId = rows.property(MySQLClient.LAST_INSERTED_ID)
            println("Last inserted id is: ${lastInsertId}")
        } else {
            println("Failure: ${ar.cause().printStackTrace()}")
        }
    }

    client.query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id=1").execute { ar ->
        if (ar.succeeded()) {
            var result = ar.result()
            println("Got ${result.size()} rows ")
        } else {
            println("Failure: ${ar.cause().stackTrace}")
        }

        // Now close the pool
        client.close()
    }

    Thread.sleep(5000)

}
```

In buld.gradle I added

```
...
dependencies {
...
implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-vertx-mysql-client")  
compile 'io.vertx:vertx-lang-kotlin:3.9.4'
```

When I debug and place a break point in "if (ar.succeeded()) {" it never reaches this line. If I place a breakpoint one line above client.query(...).execute it runs and If debug one level deeper I can see execute method is evoked but the line "if (ar.succeeded()) isn't.

And there is no error showed at all. I followed the guide as it is. Is there any other concept I have lost?   Do I have to subscribe somehow? If so, how?

*** edited

I am stillo stuck

I tried add verticle:

```
package com.mybank

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle
import io.vertx.core.Vertx
import io.vertx.kotlin.mysqlclient.mySQLConnectOptionsOf
import io.vertx.kotlin.sqlclient.poolOptionsOf
import io.vertx.mysqlclient.MySQLClient
import io.vertx.mysqlclient.MySQLPool

internal class BaseVerticle : AbstractVerticle() {
    override fun start() {

        var connectOptions = mySQLConnectOptionsOf(database = "mydb",
                host = "127.0.0.1",
                password = "password1!", port = 6603,
                user = "root")

        var poolOptions = poolOptionsOf(maxSize = 5)

        var client = MySQLPool.pool(vertx, connectOptions, poolOptions)

        client.query("INSERT INTO mytable('id','name') VALUES ('2','Jimis2')").execute { ar ->
            if (ar.succeeded()) {
                var rows = ar.result()
                var lastInsertId = rows.property(MySQLClient.LAST_INSERTED_ID)
                println("Last inserted id is: ${lastInsertId}")
            } else {
                println("Failure: ${ar.cause().printStackTrace()}")
            }
        }

        client.query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id=1").execute { ar ->
            if (ar.succeeded()) {
                var result = ar.result()
                println("Got ${result.size()} rows ")
            } else {
                println("Failure: ${ar.cause().stackTrace}")
            }

            // Now close the pool
            client.close()
        }

    }
    override fun stop() {
        println("BasicVerticle stopped")
    }
}

val vertx = Vertx.vertx()

fun main() {
    //val vertx = Vertx.vertx()
    vertx.deployVerticle(BaseVerticle())
}
```

Comment: Please a complete reproducer (including how to create the DB with Docker) on GitHub

Comment: @tsegismont, thanks for trying help me. Here you are: https://github.com/jimisdrpc/demo-vertx-mysql

Answer (score 1):

The Reactive MySQL Client executes queries asynchronously. So if you want to read the lines you have inserted, you must do it in the callback:

```
client.query("INSERT INTO mytable('id','name') VALUES ('2','Jimis2')").execute { insert ->
    if (insert.succeeded()) {

        var rows = insert.result()
        var lastInsertId = rows.property(MySQLClient.LAST_INSERTED_ID)
        println("Last inserted id is: ${lastInsertId}")

        client.query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id=1").execute { select ->
            if (select.succeeded()) {
                var result = select.result()
                println("Got ${result.size()} rows ")
            } else {
                select.cause().printStackTrace()
            }

            client.close()
        }

    } else {
        insert.cause().printStackTrace()
        client.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but as far as I can see you are doing exactly what I was trying. Can you explain a bit better what you mean by "you must do it in callback"? Well, I know whta callback means but I couldn't follow your suggestion. Should I subscribe somehow vertx.deployVerticle(BaseVerticle())?

Comment: The callback is the piece of code invoked when the execute command completes. In your question the two queries are executed concurrently, in my answer one after the other.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and, placed a breakpoint on "if (insert.succeeded()) {" and while debugging it never reaches this line. I am sure I am missing some basic concept. Please, all code is in https://github.com/jimisdrpc/demo-vertx-mysql. Kindly, can you run your eyes on it and tell me what I am missing? Is a kind of subscrition like reactive/RxJava guide us to do with some immitter (ex. Single, Flowable etc)

Comment: You may noted that from my first piece of code to the second one, I added Verticle. Well, I just did it because I read somewhere someone using it. I am still a bit lost how get my first piece of Vertx been executed